# Upserting with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pdo

I have table similar like this:

```
CREATE TABLE saldo (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    uid integer,
    value numeric(12,2),
    currency character(3)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE saldo_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO MINVALUE
    CACHE 1;
  ALTER TABLE ONLY saldo ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('saldo_id_seq'::regclass);

ALTER TABLE ONLY saldo
    ADD CONSTRAINT saldo_id_key UNIQUE (id);
```

I want to update row if exists or insert if not exists, so I found some information about upserting [here](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2013/06/efficient-upserting-in-postgresql/). It is what I got:

```
$saldo = $Db->prepare("
        WITH update_outcome AS(
            UPDATE saldo
            SET value=value+ :value
            WHERE uid=:uid AND currency=:currency
        ),
        insert_outcome AS (
            INSERT INTO
                saldo
            (uid, value, currency)
            SELECT
                :uid2 AS uid,
                :value2 AS value,
                :currency2 AS currency
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM saldo WHERE uid= :uid3 AND currency= :currency3 LIMIT 1)
        )");
        $saldo->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $saldo->bindParam(':value', $_SESSION['throw'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
        $saldo->bindParam(':currency', $_SESSION['currency'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 3);
        $saldo->bindParam(':uid2', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $saldo->bindParam(':value2', $_SESSION['throw'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
        $saldo->bindParam(':currency2', $_SESSION['currency'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 3);
        $saldo->bindParam(':uid3', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $saldo->bindParam(':currency3', $_SESSION['currency'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 3);    
        $saldo->execute();
```

I improved this query a few time, but I still get exception:
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE"
LINE 3:                 UPDATE saldo

What is wrong? Maybe there is better way to resolve this problem?

Important: there could be a few rows with this same uid, but different currency.

Answer (score 1):

You need the "with" part to be a proper query with a result. UPDATE doesn't return a result by itself, so Postgres complains about that. The example given under the link uses UPDATE .... RETURNING in the with query part to achieve that. BTW, you should always mention the PG version you are using. Also, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql?rq=1).